# Docker Unable to find file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, clair

I'm trying to build and run a docker image with `docker-compose up`
However, I get the error `can't open /config/config.template: no such file`

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM quay.io/coreos/clair-git
COPY config.template /config/config.template

#Set Defaults
ENV USER=clair PASSWORD=johnnybegood INSTANCE_NAME=postgres PORT=5432

RUN apk add gettext
CMD envsubst < /config/config.template > /config/config.yaml && rm -f /config/config.template && exec /clair -config=/config/config.yaml
ENTRYPOINT []
```

when adding the line `RUN ls -la /config/` the following is returned after running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 16 06:46 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 16 06:46 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           306 Sep  6 05:55 config.template
```

Here is the error:

```
clair_1_9345a64befa1 | /bin/sh: can't open /config/config.template: no such file
```

I've tried changing line endings and checking the docker version. It seems to work on a different machine running a different OS.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have docker version `docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306`

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  clair:
    build:
      context: clair/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - PASSWORD=johnnybegood
      - USER=clair
      - PORT=5432
      - INSTANCE=postgres
    ports:
      - "6060:6060"
      - "6061:6061"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ../blah/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=johnnybegood
      - POSTGRES_USER=clair
      - POSTGRES_DB=clair
```

Comment: Please provide `docker-compose.yaml` file contents.

Comment: Added in original post

Comment: does `config.template` is inside `../blah/postgres` folder ?

Comment: no, config.template is in the same directory as the dockerfile, (/clair)

Comment: Your context `context: ../blah/postgres` is causing the problem

Comment: The config.template should in the directory mentioned in the context.

Comment: The config.template is within the clair/ directory mentioned under clair, rather than postgres

Answer (score 0):

Docker CMD is only designed to run a single process, following the docker philosophy of one process per container. Try using a start script to modify your template and then launch clair.

```
FROM quay.io/coreos/clair-git
COPY config.template /config/config.template
COPY start.sh /start.sh

#Set Defaults
ENV USER=clair PASSWORD=johnnybegood INSTANCE_NAME=postgres PORT=5432

RUN apk add gettext
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

and have a startscript (with executable permissions) copied into the container using your Dockerfile

```
!#/bin/sh

envsubst </config/config.template > /config/config.yaml
/clair -config=/config/config.yaml
```

edit: changed the answer after a comment from David maze

Comment: It's actually important in this setup that `envsubst` not get run until container startup time.  Presumably `config.template` contains references like `$USER` and `$PASSWORD`, and this replaces them with the values specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  (I'd probably use an entrypoint script rather than the long `CMD`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't realise what envsubst did. I have changed my answer accordingly, but I don't know if a startup script is the best solution.

Comment: this causes `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory`

Comment: After some searching, I discovered that Alpine does not ship with bash, but with sh. I will change my answer, that will probably solve the problem

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same error as I did originally; `/start.sh: line 3: can't open /config/config.template: no such file`

Comment: config.template is owned by root, maybe its permissions related, I would expect another error if that was the case however.